# MATLAB parfor how to slice a matrix

Tags: matlab, parfor

I have a little parfor test script which gives the warning in the title.
The code is this

```
out = zeros(10, 1);
in = rand(5e8, 10);
tic
parfor i = 1:10
    for j = 1:5e8
        p = floor(rand(1,1)*5e8);
        out(i) = out(i) + in(p, i);
    end
end
toc
tot = sum(out)
```

the warning comes out on line 7 regarding how variable in is accessed.
I don't understand why, slicing should be trivial. Just send each column of in to each worker.
If I change the code to

```
out = zeros(10, 1);
in = rand(5e8, 10);
tic
parfor i = 1:10
    a = in(:,i);
    for j = 1:5e8
        p = floor(rand(1,1)*5e8);
        out(i) = out(i) + a(p);
    end
end
toc
tot = sum(out)
```

the warning disappears but I don't like that assignment to a.
The code was explicitly designed to mess up the cache memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as explained here http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_of7_-1 , MATLAB does not understand how to slice `in`, hence the code analyser warning. You have to read that page fairly closely to understand why it cannot be sliced. The relevant paragraph is:

> *Form of Indexing.* Within the list of indices for a sliced variable, one of these indices is of the form i, i+k, i-k, k+i, or k-i, where i
>   is the loop variable and k is a constant or a simple (nonindexed)
>   broadcast variable; **and every other index is a scalar constant, a
>   simple broadcast variable, colon, or end.**

The clause in bold type at the end is the relevant one - in your case, `p` does not match this constraint.